# Problems with KeyCode in c# UWP

Tags: c#, windows, key, uwp, keycode

I use this code to recognize which key is pressed, but when I try to recognize the arrows it just doesn't show anything or even activate the `TestFunction();`

```
private void CoreWindow_CharacterReceived(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.KeyCode == 39) //Right Arrow
    {
        //Do somthing
        TestFunction();
    }
    else //Detect All arrows KeyCode(Never display anything for this keys)
    {
        Debug.Write(args.KeyCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

PD: I use this code at execution:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;
```

Comment: are you sure you get debugger on this method?

Comment: Yes I did, I get every key but up,down,left,right,control,alt

Answer (score 1):

Arrow is not exactly a character. Maybe you should consider **KeyUp** and **KeyDown** events?

Comment: As a VirtualKey?
I've tried it already and give the same result.

Comment: Maybe it is about the focus? Take a look at this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/944e2037-e4cf-4299-9b0a-a685ff97f304/uwp-arrows-keys-as-trigger-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Maybe, But every key work, I can press space or any word but arrows or control keys not

Comment: Just to add something to the answer: I was thinking about why the *Backspace* fired the **CharacterReceived** event instead. I guess anything that can be translated to a ASCII (Unicode?) character will fire the **CharacterReceived** in addition to the **KeyDown** and **KeyUp** events. BackSpace is 8 in ASCII. However Tab and Enter are system keys and don't get through the CharacterReceived event

Answer (score 0):

> But every key work, I can press space or any word but arrows or control keys not

[CoreWindow.CharacterReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) event is fired when a new **character** is received by the input queue. A **character** is a single visual object used to represent text, numbers, or symbols. Arrows or control keys **do not represent any character**. So [CoreWindow.CharacterReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) event **won't be fired** when these keys get pressed.

If you want recognize which key on the keyboard including arrows and control, and other keys that do not represent any character is pressed, use [UIElement.KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown) or [UIElement.KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keyup.aspx) event(Occurs when a keyboard key is pressed/released while the UIElement **has focus**) instead as kra mentioned above.

Following is the simple code I have verified:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <!--Define a control which can have focus and accept input-->
    <TextBox Header="Get Focus and Press Any key on Keyboard" x:Name="txt1" KeyDown="txt1_KeyDown" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void txt1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Right Arrow key Pressed
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right)
        {
            // Do something
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Key.ToString());
            await new MessageDialog(e.Key.ToString()).ShowAsync();
        }
        // Other Keys Pressed
        await new MessageDialog(e.Key.ToString()).ShowAsync();
    }
```